# pd.describe returns non-zero mean?

Tags: pandas, statistics, normalization, data-science

I'm normalizing my data as such:
df = (df-df.mean())/df.std()

then procceed with
stats = df.describe()

Why do I get non-zero means, but std=1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mean is very close to zero, as your std is very close to 1. Python saves calculated values with a finite precision, which will result in your answers being precise up to a certain degree of precision.

Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html):

> the stored value is an approximation to the original decimal
>   fraction

Comment: I hope it is for your data!